# Ideal dimensions for an electromagnet?

Tags: dimensions, electromagnet

I've been working on a design for an electromagnet.

I've exprimented various lengths of core, and figured the height of the windings for 6 different gauges of magnet wire based on the maximum current densities (from 14 gauge 20 amperes, to 37 gauge .1 ampere) for those wires.

It turns out that, no matter the length of the core, the windings will raise ~ .57 inches above the .5112 inch core.

This would seem to suggest that the shorter the core, the better.  According  to *Design of Magnets and Electromagnets* by T.B Montgomery, though, the most efficient electromagnets are 1.5 times longer than the outside diameter.

That said, I've looked online and found professionally made electromagnets that have a greater depth than length.  The book was originally written in 1948, so it occurs that this information could have since been found false.

- Is there an ideal ratio for the length versus the width of an electromagnet?
- Does it matter if the magnet in question is using an air core or a magnetic core?  It would help simplify the selection process.

Edit:

This electromagnet is intended to push on a permanent magnet.  There are specific reasons I went with this as opposed to a standard actuator, primarily being that I needed the force to drop off as the magnet stays open.

Comment: There is no such thing as a generic (one size fits all) electromagnet.

Comment: *greater depth than length* - what does depth mean here?

Comment: @Andyaka By greater depth than length, I mean that the diameter of the core material plus the windings is larger than the length of the core.

Answer (score 3):

> Does it matter if the magnet in question is using an air core, or magnetic core?

It matters a lot. Magnetic flux flows much more easily in an iron core than in an air core.

The design of a magnet's shape is very much determined by the intended use. Magnets are usually designed to move some specific mechanism or to pick up scrap steel. Magnets for picking up scrap have a short core in comparison with diameter and an iron cover. The outside of the magnet is covered by iron that completely covers the top end and the outside leaving only an air-gap around the outside of the bottom. Actuation magnets have an iron path that conducts the flux from end to end except for an air-gap that is closed when the mechanism is actuated.

Many actuating magnets are designed in a "U" shape with the moving piece (armature) designed so that it closes the "U" shape to form a box. An "E" shape is also popular.

To determine what is most efficient, you must first define what is meant by "efficient." In engineering, the primary meaning of efficiency is thermodynamic efficiency, defined as output power divided by input power. That definition assumes continuous energy conversion or transfer. For the case in question, maximizing efficiency may mean minimizing the power required to hold something in place. It could also mean minimizing the energy required to perform one actuation. Another possibility would be minimizing the energy used by the system during a period of use.

In engineering, we try to avoid using the word efficient to describe such things as minimizing cost, environmental impact, size and weight, and depletion of natural resources.

For designing electromechanical systems, efficiency by any definition must be considered as part of a careful analysis of the task being performed. The most efficient shape of the electromechanical actuator must be determined using the dimensions, shape and other characteristics of all of the components involved.

Comment: Ferromagnetic cores also come with saturation limits, however; it's easy to get a higher flux in an iron core before the core saturates, but after saturation the core material doesn't really matter at all. The magnets used in MRI machines and particle accelerators use an air core because they need magnetic fields strong enough that any ferromagnetic core material would be far past saturation.

Comment: I meant, does the optimal geometry differ between air core and magnetic core magnets.  I.E. an air core is most efficient at 1.5 length to width whereas a magnetic core is most efficient at 2.  (These are just examples with random numbers used.)

Answer (score 2):

For an air-core solenoid, the geometry that gives the greatest magnetic field for a given quantity of conductor is to have the outer diameter of the coil to be approximately twice the inner diameter, and the cross-section of the coil to be approximately square. These dimensions give what is known as a Brooks coil.

[image]
(Image from https://coil32.net/multi-layer-coil.html)

For a ferro-magnetic core, the greatest magnetic field for a given amount of core material is a toroidal geometry. *HOWEVER*, such a geometry is *useless* as an electromagnet because, apart from leakage, the magnetic field is confined to within the core. Such a geometry provides little useful field outside of the core.

Thus, an electromagnet with a ferro-magnetic core needs an *air-gap*. The larger distance across the air gap, the weaker the magnetic field (other things being equal). However, the air gap needs to be large enough to exert the desired force on whatever the electro-magnet is used for. Thus, there is no one-size-fits-all solution.

If the purpose of the electromagnet is to hold a flat plate of ferro-magnetic material, I strongly believe that a "potted coil" would be the best. That is, the core consists of a cylinder of ferro-magnetic material with a circular channel cut into one face, with the coil nested in the channel. Something like [this](http://www.acalbfi.com/be/articles/articlesContentPage/Iron-powder-pot-cores-keep-the-flux-inside/NA-000667/TECH-005/) [image]

but open on the top, and the top of the coil flush with the face with the channel in it. [The image shows a potting core that consists of two halves that are supposed to be brought together to close the magnetic circuit. That is NOT what I mean. I mean using only one of the two core halves, and only half the coil.]

Be aware that many cores of this geometry use *ferrite* rather than "soft iron". These two materials have significantly different magnetic properties. Ferrite has lower permeability, so for an electromagnet, "soft iron" is much better. You may not be able to easily find a soft iron core in that geometry, so, for a "do-it-yourself" electromagnet, an "E" core from an "EI" transformer will probably perform much better, even though the geometry is not "ideal". Here is what I mean by the "E" core of an "EI" transformer.

[image]

(Image from https://www.delatsch.com/product/e-i-transformer-laminations/)

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient electromagnet in 2D is a circle, in order to maximize inductance/resistance ratio and B Field and thus for a 3D shape it is a Torroid.   But there are exceptions depending on the interface. For a linear force a cylinder is used and again the optimum outer/inner diameter of wire around magnetic material depends on the air gap, permeability, and slew rate limits. For DC this doesn't matter, but for AC or pulses a large inductor with low resistance has a large L/Rs=T (64%) time constant. This is inverse to frequency **(-3dB) f = 5/8 R/L**, making it slow but powerful for DC solenoids and relays with suitable speed. As R goes to zero the current rise time slows down. Yet as the diameter of the current loop increases Inductance and B force increases which increases Resistance. So there can be an optimal geometric ratio but certain assumptions on fill factor, core material and cost must be defined.

A typical relay, Contactor and solenoid aspect ratio are often built with **h/OD = 1.2** for different assumptions on iron core material. But this example  masks certain assumptions on wire OD/ID ratio, mu and cost of materials which all have a wide parameter range and thus all kinds of optimal aspect ratios occur.

Although for Maglev, with hybrid perm-electromagnets a square shape is more manufacturable, with a **long l/w,** **length/width  = 100 aspect ratio for the conductor path.**

So the end field strength or keeper Relay or pickup magnet vs core forces on moving core of your solenoid must be defined in order to optimize wire guage and OD/ID winding ratio for each core geometry.

But as I say, **"It depends on specs"** for assumptions, budget and goals.

**"You can't design anything optimally, without good specs, but with realistic specs, nothing is impossible"**